# Let p be a prime number. Find the number of prime numbers smaller than 1000 which can be written in the form $2^{p^2+1}+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find the number of prime numbers smaller than 1000 which can be written in the form $2^{p^2+1}+1$. Let p be a prime number.

how do i go by this questions?

Comment: This is always divisible $5$, except $p=2$. So, it is never a prime.

Comment: Do it one by one. As $2^{10} > 100$ then $p^2 +1 < 10$ and $p \le 3$.  So .. there's only **THREE** at most!

Comment: yes assuming that p is a prime number.

Comment: "This is always divisible 5, except p=2. So, it is never a prime"  And for $p\ne 2$ we have $2^{p^2 + 1} + 1> 1000$ so $p=2$ is the only one to consider.

Answer (score 2):

If you take $p=3$ you already get a number greater than 1000. So you just need to check what happens when $p=0,1,2$,i.e. the only possible primes of this form would be $3, 5, 33$.

edit: did not see that $p$ needs to be prime... The answer is zero, after all.

Comment: $33$ is prime??

Comment: @fleablood LOL!! My bad!!

Comment: Also, $2^{0^2+1}+1$ is $3$, not $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $p^2+1$ has an odd prime factor, say $q$. Then, we can write:
$$2^{p^2+1}+1=2^{qk}+1=(2^k)^q+1=(2^k+1)Q$$
where $Q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $Q>1$ since $(a+1) \mid (a^n+1)$ for odd $n$. This is a contradiction since $2^{p^2+1}+1$ is prime. Thus, $p^2+1$ cannot have any odd prime factors and thus must be a power of $2$.

Clearly, $p \neq 2$. As $p$ is odd, we have $p^2+1 \equiv 2 \pmod{4} \implies 4 \nmid(p^2+1)$. However, $p^2+1 \geqslant 3^2+1>4$. But, $p^2+1$ cannot be a power of $2$ greater than $4$ that is not divisible by $4$. This is once more, a contradiction. Thus, there are no such primes of the given form.

Note : One can easily check all $2^{p^2+1}+1<1000$ for primes $p$. This would conclude the answer. I wanted to show the intuition behind the question for numbers larger than $1000$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $p \geqslant 3$, then $p^2 + 1 \geqslant 10$ and hence $2^{p^2 + 1} + 1 \geqslant 2^{10} + 1 = 1025 > 1000$. If $p = 2$, then $2^{p^2 + 1} + 1 = 2^5 + 1 = 33$ is not prime. Thus there are no prime number satisfying your problem.

Answer (score 0):

$p^2+1$ is always of the form $4k+2$ for $p>2$.

So, $2^{4k+2}+1=4^{2k+1}+1=(5-1)^{2k+1}+1=5m+(-1)^{2k+1}+1=5m$.

So, it is always  divisible by $5$, not a prime.

For, $p=2$, $2^{p^2+1}+1=33$ is the not a prime. Also for $p=1$, $2^{1^2+1}+1=5$ is a prime. But $1$ isn't a prime.

Comment: You are not the only one who thinks that $33$ is prime! See PierreCarre's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

$2^{2^2+1}+1 =33$ And is not prime.

$2^{3^3+1} +1 = 1025$ which is not prime and over $1000$.

For any $p> 3$ then $2^{p^2 + 1} > 2^{3^2 + 1} > 1000$.

We're done.  There are none.

(Are you sure $p$ needs to be prime.  If $p =1$ then $2^{1^1+1} + 1 = 5$ is prime.)

Comment: the question says "Let p be a prime number."

Comment: "the question says "Let p be a prime number."  Yeah, so...?   $2$ and $3$ are prime.  There aren't any *composite* numbers less than $3$.

Comment: so there is no prime number of such form?

Comment: Well, so far as *my* answer goes there *could* be a prime $2^{p^2 + 1} + 1 > 1000$.  But Alapan Das in his/her comment answer should that for odd $p$ (which all primes other than $2$ are) then  $5$ will always divide $2^{p^2 +1} + 1$ so they can't be prime.  There might be a $\frac{ 2^{p^2+1} +1}5$ that is prime but if so it is larger than $205$